# shell: how to cut first n fields from second column

Tags: bash, shell

please help to delete first 9 fields from column number 2 (delimeter space) from a file like below.i tried using cut & awk but didnt meet required output.

my input file

```
 appu 11062017-10:00
 ammu 11062017-11:00
 anna 11062017-12:00
```

required output..

```
appu 10:00
ammu 11:00
anna 12:00
```

please note that the fields 11062017- (date) will not be same, but digit length (9 characters) will be same.
please help me with the command.

Comment: Post your attempts

Comment: Straight forward using `substr`  function in `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @anubhava's comments. It can be implemented via awk with substr.

```
awk -F  " " '{print $1,substr($2,10)}' my_input_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for headsup. Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Using awk and `sub` to replace 9 first chars of `$2` with an empty string:

```
$ awk '{sub(/.{9}/,"",$2)}1' file
appu 10:00
ammu 11:00
anna 12:00
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate awk solution

```
awk '{ split($2,arry,"-");print $1" "arry[2] }' filename
```

Here we make use of the "-" delimiter to attain the data we need

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
sed -i 's/\ .*-/\ /g' file
```

`sed` remove all characters between space  and `-`

Answer (score 0):

Another way with `sed`

```
's/\([[:digit:]]\{8\}\-\)//' filename
```

- The regex `[[:digit:]]{8}-` would match 8 digits followed by a hyphen.